# How to hide package name from actionbar tab

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

```
I am using Sherlock library for action tab bar. I have implemented custom action bar tab.
I want to hide package name from action bar.

I have marked by red color in posted screen shot
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Style:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
        <!-- the action bar dropdown menu item -->
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/actionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/actionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>


        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example1</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example1</item>
    </style>
```